# json_decode return null when a value is empty

Tags: php, php-5.3, json

I came across this problem when trying to `decode` json into an **array**, for instance,

it works fine like this,

```
$year = 2012;
$month = 3;

$json = '{"year":'.$year.', "month":'.$month.'}';
$config = json_decode($json,true);

var_dump($config); // return array.
```

but if I set one of the variable to `null`, for instance,

```
$year = 2012;
$month = null;

$json = '{"year":'.$year.', "month":'.$month.'}';
$config = json_decode($json,true);

var_dump($config); // return null
```

I am after this result,

```
array
  'year' => int 2012
  'month' => null
```

How can I return such result then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when you do

```
$json = '{"year":'.$year.', "month":'.$month.'}';
```

results in:

```
{"year":2012, "month":}
```

Which in itself is not a valid json, thus you are getting `NULL`, if you can help it do

```
$month = "null"
```

I got the following code:

```
$year = 2012;
$month = "null";

$json = '{"year":'.$year.', "month":'.$month.'}';
echo $json . "\n";
$config = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($config);
```

results:

```
{"year":2012, "month":null}
array(2) {
  ["year"]=>
  int(2012)
  ["month"]=>
  NULL
}
```